# Getting two fields from same line together

Tags: bash, text-processing

I've got a situation where I've got several lines, and I need two different fields out of each of them.  To be specific, I have a list of references in a bibliography and I want to get the last name and the year.

Sample input:

```
Aloise-Young, P.A. (1993). The development of self-presentation.  Self-promotion in 6- to 10-year-old children. Social Cognition, 11, 201-222.
Banerjee, R. (2002). Children's understanding of self-presentational behavior: Links with mental-state reasoning and the attribution of embarrassment. Merril-Palmer Quarterly, 48, 378-404.
Bennett, M., & Wellman, H. (1989). The role of second-order belief-understanding and social context in children's self-attribution of social emotions. Social Development, 9, 126-130.
```

Desired output:

```
Aloise-Young 1993
Banerjee 2002
Bennett 1989
```

I can get the last names with `cat file | cut -d, -f1`

I can get the years with `cat file | grep -o "[[:digit:]]\{4\}"`

My problem is that now I have two separate outputs and I don't know how to combine them in the way I want.  Any ideas?  I suspect maybe `awk` can do what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I put your snippet in a file called alois:

```
sed -r 's/^([^ ,]+)[^0-9]+([0-9]+).*$/\1 \2/' alois 
Aloise-Young 1993
Banerjee 2002
Bennett 1989
```

Quick explanation:
we use sed's search & replace function **s/pattern/replacement/**

^([^ ,]+)  means: from the beginning of line take anything that's not a space or a , and remember those. (that's that the parentheses are there for).

[^0-9]+  look for anything that's not a numeric value, but ignore it.

([0-9]+) take and remember any consecutive digits

.*$  match everything else to the end of line.

\1 \2   replace everything matched (the whole line) with the remembered values from above.

Comment: I'm on a Mac, so I had to use `-E` instead of `-r` flag, but that worked great after that. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

When the text processing gets too tough for basic tools, try [Awk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Awk).

```
awk -F , '{last_name = $1; sub(/\).*/, ""); sub(/.*\(/, ""); print last_name, $0}'
```

Here sed is about on par — it's less readable, but awk suffers from the lack of backreferences.

```
sed -n 's/^\([^,]*\),[^(]*(\([^()]*\)).*/\1 \2/p'
```

For this particular task, Perl is a little easier overall. You can use the non-greedy repetition operator `*?` to ensure that you capture the first parenthesized part of the line.

```
perl -l -ne '/^([^,]*),.*?\(([^()]*)\)/ and print "$1 $2"'
```

Comment: With your sed command I get this:  sed -n 's/^\([^,]*\),[^(]*([^()])$/\1 \2/p' alois 
sed: -e expression #1, char 34: invalid reference \2 on `s' command's RHS

Comment: I also got an error with the sed command and with awk one as well.  Could be because I'm running Mac, not Linux.  Perl worked straight away, though

Comment: @tink Sorry, I shouldn't have typed the commands directly in my browser. There, I've tested them and corrected them.

Comment: They all work for me now.  Thanks for all those!  I'm definitely going to study these and figure out what they're doing.  I'd upvote you if I were allowed yet

Answer (score 3):

In general, you can join the output of commands with `paste` and process substitution `<(...)`, so in your case this works:

```
 paste -d ' ' <(cut -d, -f1 file) <(grep -o "[[:digit:]]\{4\}" file)
```

Output:

```
Aloise-Young 1993
Banerjee 2002
Bennett 1989
```

But this entails passing `file` twice which is unnecessary, so you should probably be using a tool that can grab both items in one go, e.g. `sed`, `awk`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You may find out that you need to refine your requirements. For instance, none of the solutions given so far work for input like:

```
Smith, J., & 3Com(Inc.) research (1999), XYZ statistics (1960 - 1998)
```

To report everything up to the first comma along with the first occurrence of a sequence of 4 digits enclosed in parenthesis, you could do:

```
perl -ne 'print "$1 $2\n" if /^(.*?),.*?\((\d{4})\)/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sexy but you can trim the text from the first comma to the first open paren. Substitute all that with a space. Then just trim the character from the first closing paren to the end of the line.

```
1. convert this => , ..... ( to a space
2. convert this => )........ to nothing
```

#### The command

```
$ cat file | sed 's/,.*(/ /' | sed 's/).*//'
Aloise-Young 1993
Banerjee 2002
Bennett 1989
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the part after the year contains `(`, but you could use `'s/,[^(]*(/ /;s/).*//'`.

Comment: @LauriRanta - Thanks. It works for the sample data that the OP provided. If he wanted it to be more robust then he should've included more examples 8-).